# How can I apply loops and if statements to this code to speed it up?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to avoid using application as it is making my code slow

````
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
 
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub```
````

Comment: You can speed it up by not using `select` and `activate`.

Comment: There's another community called [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which was created for these kind of questions

Comment: @findwindow what is a good alternative to these to use?

Comment: Pretty much mandatory reading in the VBA world: [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: You apply the property directly to the object like `cells.entirecolumn.hidden=false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to re-work it.  I'm not sure it's going to be much faster though.

The sheet names go in an array, and you loop over that array.

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim v, arr, shtName, wb As Workbook, wsDash As Worksheet, xmax As Long, x As Long, m
    
    xmax = 23 'Number of listed utilities
    
    arr = Array("Reliability standards", "Targets", "Data quality scores", _
                "Utility scale RoS results", "Electricity Access Indicators", _
                "Customer Service Standards", "CSI Visualisation data", _
                "RoS Visualisation data")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' or ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDash = wb.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    GoFast
    
    For x = 1 To xmax 'For each utility
        If wsDash.Cells(7 + x, 8) = True Then 'Checks if the utility checkboxes are selected
            v = wsDash.Cells(7 + x, 7).Value  'value to match on
            For Each shtName In arr
                With wb.Worksheets(shtName)
                    m = Application.Match(v, .Range("5:5"), 0) 'find a match (no `.WorksheetFunction`)
                    If Not IsError(m) Then    'got a match?
                        .Cells(5, m).EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide selected utility
                    
                        Select Case shtName 'extra actions for couple of sheets
                            Case "CSI Visualisation data", "RoS Visualisation data"
                                .Cells(5, 50 + m).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                        End Select
                    Else
                        MsgBox "No match for '" & v & "' on sheet '" & shtName & "'"
                    End If
                    .Activate
                    Application.GoTo .Range("A1"), scroll:=True
                End With
            Next shtName
        End If
    Next x
    
    wsDash.Activate
    GoFast False ' turn off optimizations
End Sub

'maximize code speed by turning off unneeded stuff
'******** must reset !!!!
Sub GoFast(Optional bYesNo As Boolean = True)
  With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = Not bYesNo
      .Calculation = IIf(bYesNo, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  End With
End Sub
```